# PHP: Use the short if-statement without else?

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm a fan if the short if-version, example:

```
($thisVar == $thatVar ? doThis() : doThat());
```

I'd like to cut out the else-statement though, example:

```
($thisVar == $thatVar ? doThis());
```

However, it wont work. Is there any way to do it that I'm missing out?

Comment: No there isn't a way to do it, because it isn't a short `if`, more of a short `if/else` (although even that is just a very simplistic way of looking at it)

Comment: `[1,null][$thisVar==$thatVar] ?? doThis();`

Comment: @mickmackusa Its not. `[1, null]` is a 2 element array, and `[$thisVar==$thatVar]` is an array accessor, which accesses element 0 if its false or element 1 if its true, and element 1 will null coalesce. https://onecompiler.com/php/3xr67v6w3

Comment: @chi I see now.  I guess this is just another example of why commenting unexplained solutions under a question is not good for Stack Overflow and its readers. As a personal choice, I don't like to use this approach (ternaries) unless the outcome is being used/assigned.

Answer (score 20):

You can't use it without the `else`. But you can try this:

```
($thisVar != $thatVar ?: doThis());
```

or

```
if ($thisVar == $thatVar) doThis();
```

Answer (score 10):

The ternary operator is designed to yield one of two values. It's an expression, not a statement, and you shouldn't use it as a shorter alternative to if/else.

There is no way to leave out the `:` part: what value would the expression evaluate to if you did?

**If you're calling methods with side effects, use if/else**. Don't take short cuts. Readability is more important than saving a few characters.

Comment: I don't fully agree. imagine: 

`<li class="<?php echo $is_active ? 'active' : '' ?>">`  

 vs javascript style: 
`<li class="<?= $is_active && 'active' ?>">` 

vs react js: `<li className={is_active && 'active'}>`  

if you building lot of php sites and you use lot of conditional stuff like this its pain to always do the `: ' '` part. 

Now for "readability" imagine:
 `<li class="<?php  if($is_active): echo "active"; endif; ?>">`  the JS style php is the most readable one.

Comment: @ErikKubica Those expressions don't have side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Just use logical operators : AND, OR, &&, ||, etc.

```
($thisVar === $thatVar) && doThis();
```

a frequent use is :

```
$obj = doSomething($params) or throw new \Exception('Failed to do');
```

Answer (score 1):

USE **NULL** TO SKIP STATEMENTS WHEN IT IS IN SHORTHAND

```
$a == $b? $a = 10 : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me:

```
$leftHand != $rightHand?doThis():null;
$leftHand == $rightHand?null:doThis();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I can see, your code still uses the `else` part, so how does this solve the given question?

Answer (score 0):

hmm interesting,  because executing the below code is valid. Observe:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2) {
      echo $i;
    }
  }
```

The above code indeed, will output 13579

Notice no 'else' clause was used in the above.

If you wanted to inform the user of whether $i % 2 == FALSE ($i's divisor yielded remainder 0), you could include an else clause to print out the even numbers like shown below:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2) {
      echo "$i is odd";
      echo "<br />";
    } else {
      echo "$i is even";
      echo "<br />";
    }
  }
```

Giving you the output:
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even

I hope my amazingly easy to understand examples will help all newcomers to PHP, hands down the 'best' server-side scripting language for building dynamic web applications :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should implement a short if statement without else

```
$side = 'Right';

($side == 'Right') ? $sideValue ='Value for Right Side':'';
```

Comment: this is the same as the user don't want